# Can I create a component with a loop in vue js? Is there a way to make it recognized as html tags?

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, components, vue-component

Can I create a component with a loop in vue js?
Is there a way to make it recognized as html tags? 
Or let me know if there is any other way

```
<div v-for="(component, index) in availableComponentLists" :key="index">
  <{{component.name}}></{{component.name}}> 
  // index 0: <Yellow></Yellow>
  // index 2: <Green></Green>
</div>

export default {
 data (){
   return {
     componentLists : [
       {  
         isAppend : true,
         name : 'Yellow'
        },
        {  
         isAppend : false,
         name : 'Red'
        },
        {  
         isAppend : true,
         name : 'Green'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed : {
    availableComponentLists (){
      return this.componentLists.filter((component)=>{
        return component.isAppend
      })
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: @Steven B. thank you!!! Your answer has helped me solve the problem

Comment: you're very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).  You can render components by their names.

```js
Vue.component('yellow', {
  template: '#yellow',
  name: 'Yellow'
})

Vue.component('red', {
  template: '#red',
  name: 'Red'
})

Vue.component('green', {
  template: '#green',
  name: 'Green'
})

Vue.component('app-list', {
  template: '#list',
  name: 'app-list',
   data (){
     return {
       componentLists : [
         {  
           isAppend : true,
           name : 'yellow'
          },
          {  
           isAppend : false,
           name : 'red'
          },
          {  
           isAppend : true,
           name : 'green'
          }
        ]
      };
    },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <app-list />
</div>

<template id="list">
  <div>
    <div v-for="(component, index) in componentLists" :key="index">
      <component :is="component.name"></component>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="yellow">
  <span>Yellow Component</span>
</template>

<template id="red">
  <span>Red Component</span>
</template>

<template id="green">
  <span>Green Component</span>
</template>
```